# Extjs: I need to catch json exception into form submit response

Tags: php, json, extjs, overriding

I have a form submitting data and waiting for a json response but some errors/warnings/notices on PHP raises a javascript Exception when form tries to parse the responseText into JSON.

Is there a way to catch the error or perform my validation before form does?

I tried overriding Ext.JSON.decode, but for some reason form doesn't use that definition even when console error shows as follow

```
Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: my wrong json test!! ext-all.js:21
Ext.Error.Ext.extend.statics.raise ext-all.js:21
Ext.JSON.me.decode ext-all.js:21   <-- why Ext.JSON.[me].decode?
Ext.define.handleResponse ext-all.js:21
Ext.define.processResponse ext-all.js:21
Ext.define.onSuccess ext-all.js:21
Ext.apply.callback ext-all.js:21
Ext.define.onComplete ext-all.js:21
Ext.define.onStateChange ext-all.js:21
(anonymous function)
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code you're using, you should not try to change the behavior of Ext.JSON.decode since it may have too many unwanted consequences

Comment: You should fix your problems on the server and not output errors/warnings/notices without wrapping them in JSON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know, your comments are right but sometimes a server configuration or unexpected problem suddenly appear and I want the final user can send the error or at least not break the app. I found a workaround. Overriding Ext.form.action.Submit and encapsulating the non-json response into a valid json object. After that, calls the original onSuccess

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.action.Submit,{
    onSuccess: function( pResponse ){
        try{
            eval( "(" + pResponse.responseText + ')' );
        }catch(e){
            pResponse.responseText = '{ success: false, info: "' + pResponse.responseText.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '" }';
        }
        this.callParent( arguments );
}
});
```

It works, but assure you run this script once in the application.